# Error in sql query when datas are fetched from multiple table

Tags: mysql

```
select name from tbl_bracelets b, tbl_brooch br where b.name or br.name ='Diamond Necklce'

$res=mysql_query($qry);
```

There is an error in the above Sql query which i can't find out... Please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: provide the detailed variable - $qry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this?

```
select name
from tbl_bracelets b, tbl_brooch br
where b.name = br.name
   or br.name ='Diamond Necklce'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  select b.name from tbl_bracelets b, tbl_brooch br where b.name='Diamond Necklce' or br.name='Diamond Necklce'
```

or

```
select    name 
from     tbl_bracelets where name='Diamond Necklce'

union

select   name 
from     tbl_brooch where name='Diamond Necklce'
```